# Android project in koltin fails when execute ./gradlew build in terminal but works when run from menu

Tags: android, kotlin, android-gradle-plugin, gradlew

I'm trying to work with Travis CI, and previously I have try to build my project in the Android Studio's terminal with ./gradlew build or with ./gradlew clean build but both throws "Execution failed for task ':presentation:compileReleaseKotlin'." however when I build my project from the Android Studio's toolbar it works perfectly.

You can see the whole stacktrace and all the information here [gradle stacktrace](https://gradle.com/s/ygr3aotfbyq5y)

Thanks in advance,

Javi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your `Constants` class for errors.

```
e: /Users/jcamarero/AndroidStudioProjects/boton/presentation/src/main/java/com/b4motion/boton/utils/Constants.kt: (48, 31): Const 'val' initializer should be a constant value
e: /Users/jcamarero/AndroidStudioProjects/boton/presentation/src/main/java/com/b4motion/boton/utils/Constants.kt: (48, 46): Unresolved reference: URL_WEB_VIEW
e: /Users/jcamarero/AndroidStudioProjects/boton/presentation/src/main/java/com/b4motion/boton/utils/Constants.kt: (49, 29): Const 'val' initializer should be a constant value
e: /Users/jcamarero/AndroidStudioProjects/boton/presentation/src/main/java/com/b4motion/boton/utils/Constants.kt: (49, 44): Unresolved reference: URL_WEB_VIEW
```

This error says that you have a `const val` in your `Constants` class defined but it is not constant at compile time. Also, it cannot find reference to `URL_WEB_VIEW`.

Comment: Oh thanks you are right, do you know how could I solve it keeping the URL_WEB_VIEW constant in my BuildConfig file?

Comment: @javisilox How is URL_WEB_VIEW defined?

Comment: I'm defining it in my build.gradle file like this:

buildConfigField("String", "URL_WEB_VIEW", "\"{url preproduction}\"") 

when url preproduction is a valid url for each build type